# Ranking multiple Columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to come up with a ranking system that would take into account two separate values (from 2 different columns) and come up with a combined score (or rank).

In an ideal world, the formula would look at column(s) 'W' & 'X' and return a score that would rank these accounts from 1-1929292929292.

Even better would be a way to rank column W holding 25% and column x weighting at 75%

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102608/discussion-on-question-by-undercovernerd-ranking-multiple-columns). If there are any important points in the comments then they should be edited into the question.

Answer (score 0):

*This will help you.*

[image]

- Formula in cell `L107`:

  ```
  =RANK(H107,$H$107:$H$113)+SUMPRODUCT(--($H$107:$H$113=$H107),--(I107<$I$107:$I$113))
  ```
- Fill formula down.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*